# TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined table

Tags: javascript, html

TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined is returned when trying to retrieve first row of table_data. table_data is otherwise displayed, however, when trying to access columns or rows, an undefined error is returned.

The error occurs at line 32 of the code, where I try to print table_data.rows[0].

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#load_data').click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url:"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ishaberry/Covid19Canada/master/timeseries_canada/cases_timeseries_canada.csv",
            dataType:"text",
            success:function(data){

                var covid_data = data.split(/\r?\n|\r/);
                
                var table_data = document.createElement("table");
                table_data = '<table class="table table-bordered table-striped">';
       
                for(var count = 0; count<covid_data.length; count++){
        
                    var cell_data = covid_data[count].split(",");
                    table_data += '<tr>';
        
                    for(var cell_count=0; cell_count<cell_data.length; cell_count++){
                        if(count === 0){
                            table_data += '<th>'+cell_data[cell_count]+'</th>';
                        }
                        else{
                            table_data += '<td>'+cell_data[cell_count]+'</td>';
                        }
                    }
                    
                        table_data += '</tr>';
                }

                table_data += '</table>';

                document.body.innerHTML = table_data.rows[0];
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: The first thing you need to do is narrow it down to the specific line of code that is causing the problem.

Comment: Just updated it!

Comment: Stack Overflow doesn't provide line numbers.  Which line of code is it?

Comment: document.body.innerHTML = table_data.rows[0];

Comment: The first thing I would do is ascertain whether `rows` actually has anything in it.  Also, double-check the HTML in table_data; make sure it is well-formed.

Comment: I see that you're creating a table element (`document.createElement("table")`), and then overwriting it with text on the next line. That doesn't seem helpful.

Comment: Actually, that's your problem. You are trying to reference an HTML object with `table_data.rows[0]`, but `table_data` is a string, not an HTML object. Because you overwrote the HTML object right after you created it.  Your string will not have a `rows` property; that property belongs to a `<table>` _element_.

Comment: Ah that helps so much!